# Copying file from one destination folder to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to copy a file from one folder to another specified folder using Excel VBA Macro,my data is on Sheet 1 on Excel, I've set my file name to be on cell B5, the source folder is on B6, and the destination folder is on cell B7. This is my code below :

```
'In this Example I am Copying the File From one loaction to another location
'as per the details specified in the Worksheet.
Sub sbCopyingAFileReadFromSheet()
'Declaration
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String

sFile = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")

sSFolder = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6")

sDFolder = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7")

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
MsgBox "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder", vbInformation, "Not Found"

ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
MsgBox "Specified File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
End If
End Sub
```

but a "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder" error message keeps on popping up even though the file is in the source folder. Please assist

Comment: Are the files on a local drive like  **C:\**  or on a network drive like **\\somewhere\\** ??

Comment: what is the value in cell `B5,B6,B7`? are you including `"\"` between folderpath and filepath? is file name with its extension?

Comment: I realised I was not adding the "\" at the end of the folder path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `sSFolder & sFile` make sure you have a "\" between the 2 variables, like this

```
sSFolder & "\" & sFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Use path separator:

```
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & Application.PathSeparator & sFile) Then
```